# Add a div to custom post type's page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins, backend

Good morning everyone, i have a problem with wordpress.

[image]

When I click add button I add the structure of an html page. 
I would like to add this structure into a new div under the box add section.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Edit 1:

Maybe I find a solution.

```
    add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_meta_box', 'post_type');

function add_custom_meta_box($post_type) {
    global $post;
    if ($post_type == 'minisites') {
        add_meta_box('sections_meta_box', 'Add Section', 'show_custom_meta_box');
        echo '<div id="htmlBox" class="postbox"></div>';
    }
}
```

So, in this way I create a div when a meta box is created, after I set the content of this div with jQuery. Correct?

Comment: What you want when click on add button , a new drop down of image is add below this??.

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.